# Does completely antisymmetric tensor act on a tensor always produce a tensor or not?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, covariance

So  [completely antisymmetric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) $\epsilon$ act on a tensor can produce a new object. i.e. $G_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}F^{\mu \nu}$. However, According to Landau's Classical theory of field, $\epsilon$ are not tensor (since they do not transform as a tensor), and was called pseudo tensor.

Thus, does completely antisymmetric tensor act on a tensor always procude a tensor? and how to prove them.
(I think so because even $\epsilon$ was not a tensor, the component from the acted tensor stratify the same transformation, and their additive part should satisfy relationship to be a tensor as well.)

Comment: If your $F^{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor then your $G_{\alpha \beta}$ is a pseudotensor.

Comment: @jacob1729 in this case $G_{\alpha\beta}$ is the dual of $F^{\mu\nu}$ and is a tensor, but I'm not sure about the general cases.

Comment: It's the Levi-Civita symbol - a collection of numbers - which are independent of the metric and the coordinate system. But it can be interpreted as tensor density. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol.

Comment: Depending on the convention, this $\epsilon$ is either the Levi-Civita symbol or the Levi-Civita tensor.

Comment: @knzhou Levi-Civita is not a tensor, it does not transform as a tensor.

Comment: There is an object commonly used, which is written as $\epsilon$, and labeled by the names of Levi and Civita, which _is_ a tensor. There is also another related object that is not a tensor.

Comment: Also, the answer to your question is "no", as you can check by a simple example. For example, "1" is a rank 0 tensor. Acting on $1$ with the Levi-Civita symbol, which is not a tensor, yields the Levi-Civita symbol, which is not a tensor.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks! I think I start to get it. But is there any particular way to see if $\epsilon$ is a tensor or just the symbol? (The ambiguity was really confusing, most of the text didn't indicate it clearly.)